# How to return file from Azure Storage Account using less memory?

Tags: .net-core, azure-storage

I need help with my code. The problem is that my code loads the entire file from the Azure storage account in memory before returning it to the user I want to return the file without consuming a lot of memory. The files can be everything from 5MB to a couple of GB but when the file is large all memory is consumed and the App Service crashes.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string blobName)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob;


        await using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string blobstorageconnection = _configuration.GetValue<string>("blobstorage");
            string blobContainer = _configuration.GetValue<string>("blobcontainer");

            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobstorageconnection);
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainer);
            blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
        }

        Stream blobStream = blockBlob.OpenReadAsync().Result;
        return File(blobStream, blockBlob.Properties.ContentType, blockBlob.Name.Remove(0,9));

    }
```

Comment: You can use the `CloudBlob.OpenReadAsync` method. It will return read stream. we can directly read blob content with the stream.

Comment: @JimXu Isnt that what im already doing?

Comment: Since you have used the method, is it useful for you?

Comment: @JimXu no thats why i need help because its consuming all memory

Comment: Is that you facing the error after you remove code block ` await using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) ...` ?

Comment: That's the block fetching the file from the Storage Account.

Comment: The `OpenReadAsync` will also download the blob content.

Comment: Hi Daniel Any update?

Comment: @JimXu yeah, there was a fairly easy solution to the problem. I removed the line: await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);

And it stopped consuming the memory. So if you post the solution i can accept it.

Comment: I post my suggestion as a solution. Could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize the solution as below.

When we download the blob's content form Azure Storage using less memory, please use the method `OpenReadAsync`. It will return a readable stream then we can directly read blob content with the stream. So we do not need to provide `MemoryStream` to save content. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.openreadasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_OpenReadAsync).